# Fixed positioned element does not adapt to the width of the window/viewport

Tags: html, css, browser, position, overflow

I'm trying to make a fixed positioned navigation bar for my site with css. The problem occurs when I'm resizing the browser. The elements inside my navigation bar go out of the viewport when I resized my the browser window size.

It's a similar problem with [this](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=house-ads-at-world-employers-so&utm_content=lb3) site. When you scroll down a bit, you should see that "Products" element with a fixed positioned. Now try resize the browser window width until you can't see that "Job Listings", "Company Pages", "Candidate Search" links. Your browser should give you a scroll bar to scroll within the pages. When you scroll to the right, the pages content will get scrolled to, but this scrolling doesn't affect that "Products" element.

```
#header {
top:0px;
left:0px;
position:fixed;
height:50px;
width:100%;
z-index:100;
background:rgb(0, 0, 0);
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
padding-top:10px;
}

#nav_bar {
color:#FFFFFF;
width:894px;
margin:0 auto;
background:rgb(255, 255, 255);
background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
padding:3px;
font-weight:bold;
}

a{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
color:#F9BF3B;
background:rgb(137, 196, 244);
background:rgba(137, 196, 244, 0.5);
text-decoration:none;
}

#navlink {
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
width:100px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Any idea to solve this? Thanks. Btw [this](http://jsfiddle.net/httg1e2w/) is my code

Comment: Change it to position: absolute and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main answer to your question is:

You can't scroll the whole page (with the navbar included) because you use position: fixed.

http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/position.html

> An element with position: fixed is taken out of the normal flow of the
>   page and positioned at the desired coordinates relative to the browser
>   window. It remains at that position regardless of scrolling.

In your case, if you want to keep your navbar position:fixed, AND make all the navigation links accessible when you resize your window, I have a better suggestion:, change the width values that you've set in **pixels** into percentages and your elements will be fluid. Never use pixel width values if you want your layout to be fluid.

Here's the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/httg1e2w/3/

PS: Important: you are using "navlink" multiple times in your HTML. IDs are supposed to be Unique. Use classes instead. This may create you headaches in older browsers.

```
<a href="..." class="navlink">link</a>
```

Comment: I don't mean that I want the layout to be fluid. The point of what I'm asking is why after I decrease the browser width then I scroll the browser to the right, the page content get scrolled too. But this scrolling thing didn't affect the navigation bar. What I want is when I scroll the browser to the right, all the browser content are scrolled altogether including the page content and the navigation bar, so the links in the navigation bar will always be visible.

Comment: Well, my answer is 100 times more bulletproof and professional than scrolling, but if you insist on that, then just set overflow: auto; to your #header element. You'll get a nice (..) scrollbar when the window size is smaller.

Comment: The reason you don't get a scrollbar is because you use position: fixed. This takes the element out of the normal flow of the document. Read more about it here: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/position.html , last paragraph.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. That's creating an additional scroll on the navigation bar. I mean how to make 'as if' that the navigation bar is one packet with the page content, so when you scroll the page content, the navigation bar get scrolled too.

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer to explain why this happens and also whats the bulletproof solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok that's really helping me. Thank's a lot.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your note too. I'll surely change that navlink things.